# puppet apt class - adding a APT source with GPG key

Tags: puppet

I'm using the module:  https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apt

I configured the below class to create an additional APT source and add the GPG key.

```
class filebeats_apt {

    apt::source { 'Filebeats':
      comment  => 'Filebeats',
      location => 'https://packages.elastic.co/beats/apt',
      release  => 'stable',
      repos    => 'main',
      key      => {
        'server' => 'https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch',
        'id'     => '30239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5',
      },
      include  => {
        'src' => true,
        'deb' => true,
      },
    }
}
```

Im referencing the class in my main manifest as following:

```
# Puppetpal
node 'puppetpal' {
 include filebeats_apt
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, 
Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, validate_re():

 "30239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5" does not match 
["\\A(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\\Z", "\\A(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{16}\\Z", "\\A(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{40}\\Z"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID you posted is only 39 character long, but has to be either 8, 16 or 40 characters long. I guess you forgot to copy one character.

As a sidenote:

```
key      => {
    'server' => 'https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch',
    'id'     => '30239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5',
},
```

`server` and `id` do not require quotation marks.

Comment: thanks and now I get this: Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, validate_re(): "https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch/" does not match ["\\A((hkp|http|https):\\/\\/)?([a-z\\d])([a-z\\d-]{0,61}\\.)+[a-z\\d]+(:\\d{2,5})?$"]

Comment: As you can see from the regex, the URL has to start with either hkp://, http:// or https://

Comment: yeah strange as that's whats configured. removing https:// makes it work